# Automatically export global variable into local R function

Tags: r, environment-variables

I use a script to define some functions all depending on some common parameters. Then these functions are somehow spread "everywhere" (especially on clusters for parallel computing). Hence I cannot let them search for the variables in the `.GlobalEnv`.

For now I have been either defining them with `local(...` with or setting each time their environment. This is quite tedious. Is there a way to automatically do this sort of thing?

MWE:

```
# first solution
a = 1
fun1 <- local({
    a = a # create a copy into the new environment
    function(x) x + a
})

# 2nd solution
fun2 = function(x) x + a
myenv = as.environment(as.list(a=a))
parent.env(myenv) = .GlobalEnv
environment(fun2) = myenv
```

In both examples, independently of the environment where they are called in, `fun1` and `fun2` won't miss any argument and always be defined the same. The second solution is better because I define quite a lot of arguments, but still I have to set the environment for each function.

*EDIT*

I add an illustration of potential interest of this question:

```
> a = 1
> fun = function(x) a + x
> fun(1)
[1] 2
> rm(a)
> fun(1)
Error in fun(1) : objet 'a' not found
> a = 1
> fun = local({a=a;function(x) a + x})
> fun(1)
[1] 2
> rm(a)
> fun(1)
[1] 2
```

i.e. I want my function to be always like it was when I defined it, without paying attention to the actual environment it is called. Then for example I spread it to do some Monte Carlo simulation

```
MCsim <- foreach::times(1e4) %dopar% {fun(rnorm(1))}
```

Real examples involve more parameters and complexity

Comment: I don't understand this question. Why can't you pass a as a function parameter?

Comment: say you have 10 functions all depending on a common parameter to be set before some computer experiment, you don't want to change the default value of the variable for the 10 functions.

Comment: Sorry, I must be missing something. I still don't get what is the problem with passing as a parameter.

Comment: if you write `function(x, a=a)`, default `a` is searched in the environment where you call the function. If it is not the same as the one used to define it, at best you get an error `unknown variable` at worst it use another `a` you may not know what it is

Comment: I don't follow. When you call the function, just pass a. Why is the default relevant?

Comment: say this is some parameters of a model, not something supposed to be changed when performing simulation, thus not a variable of the function

Comment: Agree with @Roland. I think you need to provide a concrete example of something that doesn't work by passing a as parameter, otherwise can't make any sense of the question

Comment: There is still no reason to not pass as a parameter. Then foreach would export it to the workers automatically. You also could tell it to export it without passing as a parameter to your function, but why should you?

Comment: if you had a linear function `fun = function(x) a*x + b` would you give `a` and `b` as inputs and each time write `fun(x,a,b)`? or do you prefer defining them one for all, especially when you don't know nor want to know what `a` and `b` are

Comment: As a principle, I try to always pass everything needed in the function as parameters (except global constants that can be defined inside the function). I've found that this helps avoiding unpleasant surprises related to scoping. If I use parallelization I'm even more stringent in following this principle. So, I would define `fun <- function(x, a = 1, b = 0) a*x + b`.

Comment: I can make no sense of this. If you want `a` to be as you define it, then define it within your function: `function(x){ a<-1; x+a}`